# variable declared inside if any() statement is not defined?

Tags: python

I'm writing code that searches for a substring using regex and then replaces it with something else, but I'm having a problem with my "if any()" statement.

I keep getting errors that say that 'global name x is not defined', but doesn't using x inside the if any statement define the variable x in the same way that using "for x in list" makes x a defined variable that you can then use within the rest of the statement?

(for example: )

```
for x in someList:
    print x
```

What I don't understand especially is that the code DOES check if x is in the line that match the same x in the list 'reg'. If I change print x to print 'true' for example, it will print true if the expression is in the line, but it will only print once per line, even if there are more than one matches per line, and it refuses to print the actual item i'm trying to match/find!

I can't find any specific documentation for this syntax that explains it clearly.

```
    for line in inp:
        reg = a list of expressions that match a regex findall
        if any(x in line for x in reg):
             print x
```

Comment: The variable `x` is only visible inside the comprehension. It is discarded once the value of `any` is computed. You can use another `for` loop instead of `any` to check matches one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you really want is:

```
for line in inp:
    reg = a list of expressions that match a regex findall
    for x in reg:
         if x in line:
             print x
```

Or if you would want a list:

```
for line in inp:
    reg = a list of expressions that match a regex findall
    l = list(x for x in reg if x in line)
    print l
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `print` is a function, and you can do this:

```
found_something = any((x in line) and not print(x) for x in reg)
```

or

```
if any((x in line) and not print(x) for x in reg):
    # do something appropriate
```

Because `print` returns `None`, it *won't* affect the value of the `any` expression, which will also print only the `x`s that satisfy the condition.

In Python 2, you can make `print` a function using

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and then you can use the construct shown above.

Comment: ... but please don't do this in code that anyone else has to read or maintain!

Comment: Obviously it's a debugging hack ;) No matter how you print the satisfying values of `x`, the code to do so eventually has to be commented out or be deleted. Just comment it well enough, & use it while it's needed.